# illustrator cc 2014: how to change text behaviour in text box

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

When chosing the normal type tool and starting to write some text... usuallythe text is positioned nicely and I write from left to right.

Somehow this does not happen today, the text starts from the bottom right cornor and is upside down.

I am not using type on a path, this is when using the standard text tool.

Help...!

[image]

Comment: Is it with all fonts or only this one?
can you rotate it back?
does it happen in all illustrator files or only this one?
is it a text box or just text?

Answer (score 0):

It may be some error. Just a try, open new document and click Type tool

[image]

then type and see how it will looks. If not restart your application then try.